# interpret a borel-set definition of a random variable to a 101 probability theory definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I`m unfamiliar with borel sets. I encountered a proposition and I want somebody to interpret and simplify it to a 101 probability theory sentence. the proposition is:

*"The set of states of nature is taken to be $\mathbb{R}_+$. All random variables are measurable and real-valued
functions defined on the measure space ($\mathbb{R}_+$,$\mathscr{B}$($\mathbb{R}_+$)) where $\mathscr{B}$($\mathbb{R}_+$) denotes the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}_+$."*

specially I wanna understand does this proposition impose some limits on pdf of related random variables? does any continuous/discrete random variable with continuous/discontinuous/differentiable/non-differentiable pdf or cdf satisfy this proposition?

thanks a lot!

Comment: No, this definition doesn't impose any limits on the cdfs of the random variables.  For any function $F$ satisfying the properties of a cdf, you can define a random variable whose cdf is $F$.

Comment: @user6247850 would you please explain the mentioned proposition in a simple manner?

Comment: If the probability course isn't measure theory based, then this proposition doesn't really apply to anything you'll see in it.  The gist of it is "We treat random variables as functions mapping from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}_+$, and those functions have to be nice enough that we can define the CDF of the random variable."  Note that a random variable is not the same thing as its cdf or pdf, so the proposition doesn't say anything about their distribution (except that it is possible to define the cdf).